# Python Regex: Optional White Space Around Matching Group

Tags: python, regex

I would like to accept one white space before and after the **operator** group in the following regex. How would I accomplish this?

```
(?P<key>.*?)(?P<operator>NOT LIKE|LIKE|<=>|>=|<=|!=|<>|=|>|<)(?P<values>.*)
```

Three examples that I would like to match this regex would be:

```
user LIKE bob%
user=bob
user = bob
```

Comment: `(?P<key>.*?) {0,1}(?P<operator>NOT LIKE|LIKE|<=>|>=|<=|!=|<>|=|>|<) {0,1}(?P<values>.*)` should work.  Change the space to `\s` if you need to match any whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = 'user = bob'
a = re.match(r'(?P<key>.*?) ?(?P<operator>NOT LIKE|LIKE|<=>|>=|<=|!=|<>|=|>|<) ?(?P<values>.*)',text)
print a.group()
```

Output:

```
user = bob
```

if you want spaces to be part of your second group. You could do below.

```
a = re.match(r'(?P<key>.*?)(?P<operator> ?[NOT LIKE|LIKE|<=>|>=|<=|!=|<>|=|>|<] ?)(?P<values>.*)',text)
```

a.group(2)

Output:

```
 =
```

Since you mentioned whitespace(space, tab etc.) you can replace space with `\s`

Comment: OP wrote "one white space".  It's probably acceptable to accept an arbitrary number of spaces, but it's worth calling out.  Also, OP said white space not just a literal space.  So perhaps he meant to include tabs and newlines, but perhaps not.

Comment: Yes you are right, OP mentions whitespace but looking at his example looks like OP is trying to get a key values pair around a Operator seperated by a space. It's very common to refer space at whitespace but it's all assumption. Let me mention the same.